# Yearly archive page for future year

Tags: posts, wp-query, archives

There are some posts dated on future year. I would like to show them. What have I done so far:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'displayFuturePosts', 10, 2 );
function displayFuturePosts( $text, $r ) {
    return "WHERE post_status = 'future' OR post_status = 'publish'";
}
wp_get_archives(array( 'type'=>'yearly' ));
```

This show three links: 2016 2017 2018

First two opens and shows all the posts, but 2018 redirects to 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add future posts to the query.

```
function add_future_posts($query) {
    $query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'future'));
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_future_posts', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Just add the code I gave you to the functions.php